# Public to private using reflection

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to do something like the following code:

```
public class Connector {
     public static Connection getConnection() {
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String, String, String);
         conn.getClass().getMethod("close").setAccessible(false); // this is what i am trying to achieve
     }
     public static void close(Connection c) {
         c.getClass().getMethod("close").setAccessible(true);
         try{ c.close(); }
         catch(Throwable e) {}
     }
}
```

I want to prevent others from invoking `conn.close()` and force them to use `Connector.close()` because sometimes `conn.close()` throws `NullPointerException` when invoked. Is it even possible?

Comment: Why would anyone ever has access to a `Connection` in a JSP? Simply don't give them one and they cannot call `close()` on it. Remove `getConnection` entirely.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I want to restrict anybody invoking `conn.close()` directly, it does not matter weather the caller is invoking the method from `jsp`.

Comment: You can easily prevent it at runtime by throwing an exception, but you seem to want to prevent it at compile time. So if you don't want people to call `close()` don't give them a `Connection`.

Comment: You can't reference an instance member from a static method.

Comment: Why can't you encapsulate and then call the function only if needed? I would still go with the @BoristheSpider way of doing this, don't give them the access at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write your own class loader,
that is terrible.

Instead create your own class,
perhaps named `RestrictedConnection` and use composition to contain a real `Connection`.

Next, just don't provide a `close` method for the RestrictedConnection class.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, something like this might be possible using "class loader magic".

In other words: you could create your own class loader, that manipulates specific classes whilst loading them.

Using reflection like proposed in the question is most likely not going to work. Keep in mind: reflection is primarily about *reflecting* on code structure. Yes, prior Java 9 you can easily turn to "low level" and change the accessibility of fields (unless a security manager is in place), but beyond that reflection does **not** allow for **changing** code structure. It is meant for *inspection*, not *manipulation*.

So, the *real* answer is: do **not** do that. Rather think up proper, clean interfaces that people are supposed to use.

There is no point in making something public to later, at runtime, reduce it to less than that. This is the opposite of "proper OOP".

Answer (score 1):

> I want to prevent others from invoking `conn.close()` and force people to use `Connector.close()` because sometimes `conn.close()` throws `NullPointerException` when called from jsp. Is it even possible?

Even if it *were* possible, it would not serve your purpose.  You would just change the exception that occurs when JSP code attempted to invoke `Connection.close()`, quite possibly to an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.  That's not better.

Leaving aside the question of whether it's a good idea for your JSPs to have direct access to a `Connection` in the first place, or to invoke its `close()` method, the fact that you sometimes get an NPE signals a flaw in your application logic.  You should track that down and fix it -- why your JSPs sometimes get `null` instead of a *bona fide* `Connection` -- rather than trying to put a band aid over the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper object that only contains the Connection object and which reroutes every cllas to the underlying Connection, exept close.

```
public class CustomConnection {
    private Connection conn;
    public CustomConnection( Connection conn ) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public void close() {
       throw new ForbiddenException();
    }

    public void commit() {
        this.conn.commit();
    }

    ....

}
```

And change your Connector  class:

```
public class Connector {
     public static CustomConnection getConnection() {
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String, String, String);
         return new CustomConnection( conn );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best options are:

- Subclass connection and throw an exception if anyone calls close. This is the simpler option, won't give a compile time error but calling it will never work, and people won't do it (instead of doing it because it worked once and then getting errors later).
- Create an Annotation Preprocessor to give a compile time error when the method is called in the user code. That is more difficult and convoluted, and might not be the best approach, but will give an error on compilation, which is always better.

Using Reflection, if it is possible, will give at most a Runtime error anyway, so in this case I'd rather option one that is simpler and more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe no one mentioned this: **deprecate it, remove it in a later version**

---

Turning a `public` into a method `private` can result in code breakage.

Best way to handle this situation: inform others "*this may be removed in the future*": give them time to update their code before breaking older versions.

This is what `@Deprecated` is for. If others depend on their code, don't break it without warning. Later on, you can remove it, with the assurance that you told dependers it'll no longer be accessible.

Yes, users will still be able to use it. But at least they'll know they *shouldn't* use it. The benefit is giving developers who depend on your code time to update their software, opposed to breaking their software instantly.

Comment: umm, because using `Deprecated` annotation is not the concern here

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Sorry, the post may have been too abstract. Boris mentioned your issue in the comments: overexposure. You don't want devs to access something they currently have access to (`Connection#close`). Turing a public contract from `public` to `private` results in breaking code (which you don't want to do.. if people already call `Connection#close`, then making it private would cause errors in their software, unless they updated it). `Deprecated` not only gives time for devs to update, but allows you expose a proepr way. As Boris said, you shouldn't even be exposing `getConnection()`.